# Recyclerview Glide Loadmore is so heavy load and lag in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have an issue with my recyclerview.
Overview :

[**Background**]

The server has >1000 item. Each item has name and image URL attributes.
We pageable this by 30 items/request to apply load more in recyclerview in Android.
So, in the client, we use [Xrecyclerview Lib](https://github.com/XRecyclerView/XRecyclerView) to show the list. Request API to get list response (**request api in Worker Thread**).

We apply load more when reaching to the end of the list.
We use Glide to load image to Item View (**Load image to ImageView in Main Thread**).

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
    options.timeout(10000);
    Glide.with(toImageView.getContext())
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .thumbnail(0.3f)
            .apply(options)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
            .into(toImageView);
```

Some first item renders well, however when a lot of item, my list is render so lag, frezze when user scroll.

Video belove (Lag from 02:00):
[Link Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DM7xQ5m0KXDuevNc68ELs7pe-u2kQsVk/view?usp=sharing)

**[My Solution]**

I try many solutions to optimize my list:

1. I set my ImageView with a specific width, height size.
   ---> Not working
2. I set the thumbnail to Glide to 0.3f to load faster
   ---> Not Working
3. I try to not render my Image, just show text.
   ---> The lag is reduced, so I think the problem is rendering Image by Glide.

**[Help]**

Anyone has the solution to reduce lag when scroll and load more item in recyclerview for me.
Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the size of the images you are loading? Secondly, `0.3f` won't help as Glide download the whole URL first and then sets the same to the 0.3% quality of it. Thirdly, do you need to load it `asBitmap()` in your ImageView? I would also suggest you to use `: DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC ` instead.

Comment: The Image has <500kb size. I try remove 0.3f and asBitmap()  , however it not work.

Comment: It does not work as in the image is not loading anymore or is it still loading slow? Also if possible could you share some sample image link?

Comment: I confirm Image still load, however, it loads slow and the scroll is so lag and froze the app while loading the image. The resource Image , I got from google. any image with size <500kb.

Comment: I feel this could be some external issue, since I also user Glide in my projects and just as you we use pagination to loadMore so at a time only some elements are visible on screen and as such if every image is <500kb, it should not be an issue at all.

Maybe the recyclerView is not working properly.

Comment: @che10 Can you give me some your code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233224/discussion-between-dng-nguyn-vn-and-che10).

Comment: I use the default options, so it is just as simple as this `Glide.with(this).load(url).into(image_view)`. Beside this we use the `error` and `placeholder` option to set those in case something goes wrong.